# Full Calendar changes not persisting: event drag and event resize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I have installed full calendar into my ruby on rails app. I cannot figure out why changes are not persisting. I want to use the drag/drop and resize features. I have followed their documents but I'm stuck.

I think i've made an error on callback url?

I appreciate the help!

Fullcalendar docs:

```
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventResize
```

appointment_calendar.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var arr = $('#business_appointment').data('url');

      var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek',
        },

      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      nowIndicator: true,
      timezone: "Australia/Brisbane",
      events: arr,
      //header and other values
      select: function(start, end, allDay) {
          starttime = moment(start).format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");
          endtime = moment(end).format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");
          todaytime = moment().format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");
          var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
          $('#createEventModal #appointment_from').val(starttime);
          $('#createEventModal #appointment_to').val(endtime);
          $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
          $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
          $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
       },

       eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
          event_data = {
            event: {
              id: event.id,
              start: event.start.format(),
              end: event.end.format()
            }
          };
          $.ajax({
              url: "/app/calendar/" + calEvent.id  + "/edit",
              data: event_data,
              type: 'PATCH'
          });
        },

        eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

          alert(event.title + " end is now " + event.end.format());

          if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
            revertFunc();
          }

        },

       eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/app/calendar/" + calEvent.id  + "/edit",
            dataType: "script"
          });

        },
        eventRender: function(event, element)
        {
            element.find('.fc-time').append("<br/>" + event.residentname);
            element.find('.fc-time').append("<br/>" + event.appointmenttype);
        }

    });


    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
    // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
        e.preventDefault();

        doSubmit();
    });

    function doSubmit(){
        $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
        console.log($('#apptStartTime').val());
        console.log($('#apptEndTime').val());
        console.log($('#apptAllDay').val());

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
            title: $('#residentName').val(),
            start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
            end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
            allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
        },
        true);
    }

});
```

calendar_controller.rb:

```
require "datetime_format"
class App::CalendarController < App::BaseController
include DateTimeFormat
  before_action :set_appointment, only: [:edit,:update]
  def index
    @arr = []
    @business_appointments = current_business.appointments
    @business_appointments.each do |business_appointment|
      hash = {}
      hash["start"] = business_appointment.start
      hash["end"] = business_appointment.end
      hash["title"] = business_appointment.name
      hash["residentname"] = "#{business_appointment.resident.first_name} #{business_appointment.resident.last_name}"
      hash["appointmenttype"] = business_appointment.appointment_type.name
      hash["id"] = business_appointment.id
      @arr << hash
    end
    @global_arr = @arr
    @appointment = current_business.appointments.new
  end

  # POST/calender_appointment
  def create
    @appointment = current_business.appointments.new(appointment_params)
    @appointment.author_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.save!
        format.html { redirect_to app_calendar_index_path, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to app_calendar_index_path, notice: 'Unable to create appointment.' }
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /update_calender_appointment
  def update
    @appointment.author_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.update(appointment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to app_calendar_index_path, notice: 'Appointment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to app_calendar_index_path, notice: 'Unable to update appointment.' }
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private

  def set_appointment
    @appointment = current_business.appointments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def appointment_params
    if params[:action].eql?("create")
      params[:appointment][:start] = format_datetime(params[:start]).to_datetime
      params[:appointment][:end] = format_datetime(params[:end]).to_datetime
    end
    params.require(:appointment).permit(:name, :description, :start, :end, :resident_id, :appointment_type_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: not persisting where? On the calendar or in your database? Any console errors in your browser?

Comment: On refresh calendar page it returns to the previous position. Unchanged on DB.  @ADyson

Comment: ok well you aren't saving it to your database during the eventResize event, so I'm not sure why you'd expect it to persist? You'd need to update your server the same way you do during eventDrop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my error, needed to add this code:

```
updateAppointment = (event) => {
  let event_data = {
    appointment: {
      id: event.id,
      start: event.start.format(),
      end: event.end.format()
    }
  };
   $.ajax({
      url: "/app/calendar/" + event.id,
      data: event_data,
      type: 'PUT'
  });
}
```